# Using LeakCanary on project with Realm

Tags: android, realm, leakcanary

I have an android project that uses Realm.
I'm trying to integrate LeakCanary to find memory leaks, but when LeakCanary tries to create report, it crashes with exception

```
encrypted.realm: Encrypted interprocess sharing is currently unsupported
```

As I understand, LeakCanary tries to access Realm from different process, that causes crash.

How to fix this problem? Is anybody using Realm and LeakCanary in project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I found in this topic https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/3053 you can skip Realm initialization for LeakCanary process in this way

```
 if (!LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(this)) {
            byte[] key = new byte[64];
            Arrays.fill(key, (byte) 0);

            config = new RealmConfiguration.Builder(this).encryptionKey(key).build();
            realm = DynamicRealm.getInstance(config);
        }
```

Or, if you still need Realm, you can create dumb realm config

```
Realm.init(context);

if (LeakCanary.isInAnalyzerProcess(context)) {
    return new RealmConfiguration.Builder().build();
}
```

Comment: You probably shouldn't need Realm in the analyzer process.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce sure, but it can be not so easy to get rid of Realm initialization, as it could be buried deeply in Dagger modules

Comment: Really? I've never had that problem